# increase upload_max_filesize with php.ini

Tags: file-uploads, php

I'm trying to increase the upload file size for my EE installation to 120MB.  I have verified that I can modify these settings with my hosting service by adding a php.ini file to my webspace and placing the following code in it:

```
upload_max_filesize=120M
```

I have done this, and when I go to utilities and view the setting for that parameter, it shows that its been changed to 120M, but I am not able to upload a file that is 14.7MB.  I get an error in EE stating that the file size has exceeded the limits in my php configuration.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting

```
post_max_size=120M
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple PHP settings you should change to allow for larger file uploads:

- upload_max_filesize
- max_input_time
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

This [**page gives details**](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php).